# Pairwise t test (holm correction) with ezANOVA output

Tags: r, t-test

I'm doing data analysis using R (dyplr).

I'd like to perform post-hoc comparisons using the pairwise.t.test() function in R and the output of the ANOVA I performed with ezANOVA() but I don't know how.
I'd like to perform post-hoc comparisons for the group factor (3 levels).

Here is the code for the ANOVA

```
anova_age = ezANOVA(data = data_age_anova,
                       dv = age_years,
                       wid = participant_id,
                       between = group,
                       type = 3,
                       return_aov = T)
```

Once the assumptions are checked, how shall I use the pairwise.t.test() function we the output of my ANOVA to perform post-hoc t-test with Holm correction?

Comment: Its not clear if this question is about the statistical operations behind employing post hoc tests to ANOVA or about the programming aspects of this. If it is the former, then the question belongs here. If it is the latter, it is off topic and belongs on other sites like Stack Overflow.